# Spring security base path redirection

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I the base uri of my application is `localhost:8080/COMEI_Beneficiario` but I must write `localhost:8080/COMEI_Beneficiario/login` in order to access. In other applications, it redirects itself to `/login` when the base uri is written, but I'm not able to find the difference between the configurations. Below you will find the .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">



    <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/jcaptcha" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/olvidePassword" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/recovery/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/usuario/*" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/paginaMensajes" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/menu" access="hasRole('MENU_BENEFICIARIO')" />

<!--        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('0')"/> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="cartilla" access=" hasRole('BENEFICIARIO')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/cartilla/**" access=" hasRole('BENEFICIARIO')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="consumos" access=" hasRole('CONSUMOS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/consumos/**" access=" hasRole('CONSUMOS')" />
<!--        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('0')" /> -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/menu"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" always-use-default-target="true"  
    />


        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout"/>
    </http>

<authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">

      </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure whether it is best practice or not:
In controller add a method like below

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/login","/"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(){
   return "redirect:login";
}
```

Second way is write a `login.jsp` and make this jsp as welcome file in `web.xml`. in login.jsp use response implicit object redirect to "login".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved the way you proposed, but I'll try to get it done by security xml.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security will redirect to the login page if user is anonymous and anonymous access is forbidden for the requested path. Your first rule:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
```

It allows anonymous access to the base URL, thus no redirect.

Note! Intercept rules are evaluated in the order the are declared, stopping after first match; in other words: `/**` should always be last.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I deleted that line, but I still don't have the redirection.

Comment: @LukeSpringWalker Try reintroduce one of the `intercept-url` rules you have commented out.